# Python Dataframe For loop (if i.contains)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I need a for loop on a column specific. With this for loop, I will assign the value 'Normal' to a list if the column contains 'Themes'. But I don't know how to write it here. I would be glad if you help. Thanks in advance :)
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZOT5.png)

[For loops that I try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldoSB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.where` which is basically an `if-else` statement:

```
df['group'] = np.where(df['Developer ID'].str.contains('Themes'), 'Normal', 'Premium')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop via apply-lambda too;

```
df["group"] = df["Developer Id"].apply(lambda x: "Normal" if "themes" in str(x).lower() else "Premium")
```